# jquery.repeater has a problem with setList function to Render Multiple Groups

Tags: jquery, jquery.repeater

Jquery Repeater code, I have problem with if I am adding multiple groups and use setList function then its always set fields values for last group, not for all group.

For Example;

```
<form class="repeater">
    <div data-repeater-list="group-a">
        <div data-repeater-item>
            <input type="text" name="input-field-name-1" value=""/>
            <input type="text" name="input-field-name-2" value=""/>
            <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add"/>
</form>
<form class="repeater">
    <div data-repeater-list="group-b">
        <div data-repeater-item>
            <input type="text" name="input-field-name-1" value=""/>
            <input type="text" name="input-field-name-2" value=""/>
            <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add"/>
</form>

<script>
    var myJson = '{"group-a":[{"input-field-name-1":"Apple","input-field-name-2":"5"}], "group-b":[{"input-field-name-1":"Mango","input-field-name-2":"10"}]}';
    var myObj = JSON.parse(myJson);

    var $repeater = $(".repeater").repeater();
    $repeater.setList(myObj["group-a"]);
    $repeater.setList(myObj["group-b"]);
</script>
```

I want to set all repeater groups(like group-a, group-b have each group wise set field values based on setList JSON) fields values with multiple times(getting/setting into JSON format) for multiple groups.

Library:

https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater

Some reference:

https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater/issues/46#issuecomment-280854544